# only one mapper and reducer are running even though i change to 5 mappers and 2 reducers

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I am new to `Hadoop`, and i have set one multinode Hadoop with `Hadoop 2.5.1` version.
When i run a mapreduce job using command

```
hadoop jar jarFile <ClassName> <InputFile> <outputDirectory> -D mapreduce.job.reduces=2 mapreduce.job.maps=5
```

But when i see output i see only one mapper and one reducer running.

And i see there is no concept of map slot and reducer slot in `Hadoop 2.5.1`

And my file size is `78MB`. So is that the reason as my file size is quite less, and blocks are very low so there is only one mapper running?

Help in this would be great for me to go ahead.

Thanks & Regards,
Srilatha K.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the default size of the block is 128MB and hence your file of size 78M never got splitted accross multiple blocks. See [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) which says default block size is 128.

If you want to see two mapper then add the following lines in $HADOOP_HOME/conf/hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
   <name>dfs.blocksize</name>
   <value>64M</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Almas, but i even have one question. I have another singlenode cluster with Hadoop 1.0.4. when i run same MR job in that clusetr i see 2 map tasks running, i have tried changing block size and even -D mapreduce.job.maps=1. But still i see 2 map tasks running. Could you help me out in this, like exactly where should i modify to see only one Map task running.

Comment: That's because in 1.0.4, default block size was 64M. See [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/hdfs-default.html) for details about default properties.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer Almas, but i have changed that default size to 128M started all services and checked , still iam having 2 mappers, so any special reason for this kind of behaviour?

Comment: still you have two blocks. Format your name node, put that file again, this will make your file allocation within a single block and rerun your mapred and check. If you dont want to format, then put that file in another location and give that as input to your mapred call.

Comment: But i have tried both approaches, formated namenode and tried copying file again and even placed file in another location without formating namenode still i see problem . I see 2 mappers.

Comment: check your number of block allocated for your new file from block scanner on web and see if it splitted file into two blocks or one block. i doubt it will be as is with one block or you might have chosen the same command as you ran last time.